# SQLAlchemy query where a column contains a substring

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'm constructing a query using SQLAlchemy and SQLite3 in which I'd like to select rows in which a String column contains a particular substring. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Filter by `db.table.column.like('%needle%')`. There is also `ilike` for a case insensitive search.

For a fancier interface you can allow for the known "dir" wildcards.

```
if '*' in needle or '_' in needle: 
    looking_for = needle.replace('_', '__')\
                        .replace('*', '%')\
                        .replace('?', '_')
else:
    looking_for = '%{0}%'.format(needle)

result = db.table.filter(db.table.column.ilike(looking_for))
```

Notes:

- The `db.table.filter` and `db.table.column` is for `SQLSoup` ([SQLSoup](https://sqlsoup.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is useful if the database was made by another application)
- for SQLAlchemy Core it is `select(column_list).where(table.c.column.ilike(expr))`. This interface is the way to go when you want all the power from raw SQL without having to compose statements by hand using string interpolation (use it along SQLSoup for introspection, so you don't need to declare tables)
- for SQLAlchemy Declarative (the one used in Flask) it is `Model.query.filter(Model.field.ilike(expr))`

Comment: Can you tell us the query in Flask-SQLAlchemy

Comment: @Wally Flask-SQLAlchemy is a convenience package to connect SQLAlchemy to Flask. Querying doesn't change compared to SQLAlchemy Declarative.

Answer (score 128):

You can filter using [`contains`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnOperators.contains) operator:

```
Model.query.filter(Model.columnName.contains('sub_string'))
```

To negate in, use [`not_`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.not_) operator with it:

```
Model.query.filter(not_(Model.columnName.contains('sub_string')))
```

For case-insensitive matching, SQLAlchemy 2.0+ includes the `icontains()` operator ([changelog entry](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/changelog/changelog_20.html#change-22fe9fadf6dd1bf4c2d29a4cfd5db4d9)).

Comment: Thanks for this answer. You've solved my problem. But can you give details about this function. I want to know how it works.

Comment: @Wally [sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter)

Comment: @Wally have just revisited this comment which wasn't very helpful - sorry. This is better [sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.QueryableAttribute.contains](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/internals.html?highlight=contains#sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.QueryableAttribute.contains)

Comment: Further comments on Bluehorn's answer, but I've come across situations where like(%...%) works but contains() simply doesn't. Don't know why just yet.

Answer (score 19):

While `table.c.column.like("%...%")` should work, there is a more direct way to say what you want:

```
table.c.column.contains("needle")
```

This will usually generate the same SQL query but it is better to read for the uninitiated.
Note that contains does not seem to escape **"_"** and **"%"**.

Comment: like(%...%) isn't as direct, no - but I have a group of tables (models) that turn field.contains(k) into field LIKE '%%' || k || '%%' every time - not rendering the correct results.

Comment: TIL: You can add `autoescape=True` to do [escaping with the contains function](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnElement.contains)

Answer (score 5):

```
@app.route('/<var>', methods=['GET'])
def getdb(var):
    look_for = '%{0}%'.format(var)
    log1 = table.query.filter(table.col.like(look_for))
```

I've used SQLAlchemy and Flask (app.route on top is a decorator).
I used the get API to take in the variable that the user wishes to search for and I'm converting that variable to store it in another variable called look_for(since var cannot be used directly in the query) by using the format() and log1 stores the queried tuples.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to di in the newest versions of sqlalchemy

```py
query = select(table_name).where(table_name.column.contains("value_youre_searching_for"))
results = await db.execute(query)
data = results.scalars().all()
```