# SQLAlchemy query where a column is a substring of another string

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

This question is similar to [SQLAlchemy query where a column contains a substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926757/sqlalchemy-query-where-a-column-contains-a-substring), but the other way around: I'm trying to query a column containing a string which is a sub-string of another given string. How can I achieve this?

Here is a code example of a database set up using the ORM:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.sql import exists

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')
Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    url = Column(String)
    fullname = Column(String)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
session.add_all([
    User(url='john', fullname='John Doe'),
    User(url='mary', fullname='Mary Contrary')
])

session.commit()
```

The following works:

```
e = session.query(exists().where(User.url == 'john')).scalar()
```

upon which `e` has the value `True`. However, I would like to do something like

```
e = session.query(exists().where(User.url in 'johndoe')).scalar()
```

where `in` is in the sense of the `__contains__` method of Python's string type. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just like (heh) the linked question, except you turn it around:

```
SELECT ... WHERE 'johndoe' LIKE '%' || url || '%';
```

You'll need to take care to escape special characters if you've got those in your table:

```
SELECT ... WHERE 'johndoe' LIKE '%' || replace(replace(replace(url, '\', '\\'), '%', '\%'), '_', '\_') ESCAPE '\';
```

In SQLAlchemy:

```
escaped_url = func.replace(func.replace(func.replace(User.url, "\\", "\\\\"),
                                        "%", "\\%"),
                           "_", "\\_")
session.query(... .where(literal("johndoe").like("%" + escaped_url + "%", escape="\\")))
```

Note the escaped backslashes in Python.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, what worked for me was `from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import literal` followed by `e = session.query(exists().where(literal('johndoe').like('%' + User.url + '%'))).scalar()`, upon which `e` is `True`. (This actually also worked with 'real' URLs without any escaping).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `like`

```
e = session.query(exists().where(User.url.like("%{}%".format('put your string here')))).scalar()
```

Comment: This doesn't work: if I run `e = session.query(exists().where(User.url.like('%johndoe%'))).scalar()`, then `e` is `False`, whereas I want it to be `True`.